# Determine Azure Pipeline success based on logs

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

How to determine success or failure in Azure Pipeline stage, based on logs?

I have following output and I'd like to set status as failed based on message from logs.

[image]

How to edit .yaml file to achieve this?
My .yaml step looks like:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: Deploy function ${{ parameters.package_name }}
        retryCountOnTaskFailure: 10
        inputs:
          workingDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/${{ parameters.package_name }}
          azureSubscription: ${{ variables.azure_subscription }}
          scriptType: bash
          scriptLocation: inlineScript
          inlineScript: >
            func azure functionapp publish func-tfm-${{ parameters.package_name }}-${{ variables.env_reg_long }} --python
```

Comment: What's the YAML for that step like?

Comment: Just added it to my question. This is exact task, because step is very complex.

Comment: @Maciek, may i know if there's any update? let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

Ah it's a script step, that makes things easier.

You can capture the output from az into a variable, then check the output.

```
$output= & az ... ... ...
if ($output -like "*the errormessage*')
{
  echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
}
```

If you still want to stream the content it's a little more work.

In many cases, instead of checking the contents, you can probably check the last exit code:

```
& az ... ... ...
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed
}
```

You may also be able to set the property on the script step to fail on output to Standard Error:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  failOnStandardError: true
  powerShellErrorActionPreference: "stop"
```

Comment: Ohh wait I only now see you're using bash, the examples I gave are for powershell, the same principle applies though

Answer (score 1):

An example of capturing the error code from a bash command:

```bash
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can **output** the result of command:

```
func azure functionapp publish <appname> --output json > log.json
```

then parse the json file, use `grep -q` to check if it contains the error message. According to the result, use logging command `echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"` to set the task as fail.

I created python function app, and sample as below:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Deploy function app
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn2'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      func azure functionapp publish wadetest1 --python --output json > log.json
      if grep -q "the error message" log.json; then
          echo "##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Failed"
      fi
```

My pipeline result when the message found in log, it works as expected.

[image]